# Size issue when adding a background image in the TopLeftHeaderCell

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to add a background image in the TopLeftHeaderCell of a custom datagridview.

The original image resolution is 835x835, so i resized it to the TopLeftHeaderCell size but it results with a full black colored TopLeftHeaderCell, as if the image wasn't resized.

Here's my code :

```
Private Sub dtg_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles Me.CellPainting
    
    If e.RowIndex < 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then
        Dim dgvCellTopLeftHeader As DataGridViewCell = Me.TopLeftHeaderCell
        Dim bmpTopLeftHeaderResized As Bitmap = New Bitmap(My.Resources.Resources.expand_black, New Size(dgvCellTopLeftHeader.Size.Width, dgvCellTopLeftHeader.Size.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpTopLeftHeaderResized, e.CellBounds)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

Thanks to Jimi, here's my final code to have a centered custom image in the top left header cell:

```
If e.RowIndex < 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.CellBounds.X + 2, e.CellBounds.Y + 1, CInt(e.CellBounds.Width * 0.85), CInt(e.CellBounds.Height * 0.85))
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Dumbow_2.My.Resources.Resources.expand_black_128, e.CellBounds.X + 10, e.CellBounds.Y + 4, CInt(e.CellBounds.Width * 0.5), CInt(e.CellBounds.Height * 0.55))
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Comment: Just set the size to the current Cell's bounds.  Assign the Bitmap to a Field: `private headerBmp as Bitmap = [Some Image From Resource]`, then draw it when requested: `e.Graphics?.DrawImage(headerBmp, e.CellBounds) e.Handled = true` --> The Bitmap object should be assigned to Field because the Resource manager generates a new object each time you ask for one, and you never dispose of it. Dispose of the Bitmap Field when the parent Form closes --  Remove that `TopLeftHeaderCell`

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't fix the issue. The "TopLeftHeaderCell" is still full black...
```Private bmpHeader As Bitmap = Dumbow_2.My.Resources.Resources.expand_black
If e.RowIndex < 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then
    Dim bmpTopLeftHeaderResized As Bitmap = New Bitmap(bmpHeader, New Size(e.CellBounds.Size.Width, e.CellBounds.Size.Height))
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpTopLeftHeaderResized, e.CellBounds)
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Comment: As mentioned, **do not create a new Bitmap** (when and how are you going to dispose of it?), use the exiting one. So, in your CellPainting event handler, just write `If e.RowIndex = -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = -1 Then e.Graphics?.DrawImage(bmpHeader, e.CellBounds) e.Handled = true end if` -- This assumes the image, when shrunk to a tiny size, is still recognizable

Comment: "This assumes the image, when shrunk to a tiny size, is still recognizable", i thought the cause of the issue was here because the cell is still full black. I guessed the shrunk image didn't display well so i tried with a version of the image shrunk to 128x128 it didn't solve the issue. I noticed that the image is black.
So, I tried with an other image, a red one and it works but i noticed the background of the cell is black, that explains (even if i don't get why)

Comment: Mentioned multiple times: **don't use `My.Resources` directly**; it's a Factory, it generates a new Bitmap each time. Assign the Image to a Field beforehand and use that, so it's created just once

Comment: Sorry but i don't get/know how to "Assign the Image to a Field beforehand"

Comment: First comment: `private headerBmp as Bitmap = [Some Image From Resources]`. Then of course draw the `headerBmp` object